# Drop rows that dont fulfill a certain equation condition except the rows with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have the following dataframe

```
    Year  Company   BS_02Liabilities    BS_03Equity  BS_01Assets
0   2010  Adidas    9                   NaN          10
1   2011  Adidas    10                  10           30
```

I would like to check when the relationship MTOT = M1 + M2 is violated by a certain threshold say 5 and drop the rows where this happens.

This is the code I tried:

```
threshold = 5
MTOT='BS_01Assets'
M1='BS_02Liabilities'
M2='BS_03Equity'
_mask = (abs(df2[MTOT] - (df2[M1] + df2[M2])) > threshold)
df2.loc[_mask==True, [MTOT, M1, M2]].dropna()
df2.drop(df2.loc[_mask==True, [MTOT, M1, M2]].dropna().index)
```

This works for row 1 because 30 is bigger than 10 + 10 by more than 5.
However it also drops the rows where a value in the equation is NaN here row 0.
But I want to keep rows where its not possible to verify the equation.

How do I tell python to only drop values where we can actually verify the equation and keep values where the equation is correct or where it is not possible to calculate the equation because of a NaN.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fillna`:

```
_mask = (abs(df2[MTOT] - (df2[M1].fillna(0) + df2[M2].fillna(0))) > threshold)
```

Comment: The problem is I already have data with zeros so if I fill in the NaN's with zeros I will not be able to differentiate the zeros and the NaN's